# Can FHIR MedicationPrescription.dosageInstruction.doseQuantity handle a dose range?

Tags: hl7-fhir

If the dose is expressed as a range, such as 1 - 3, can this be handled with the FHIR MedicationPrescription.dosageInstruction.doseQuantity ?

Comment: No answer yet - but I am investigating

Comment: Thanks for checking - perhaps Pharmacy groups should review. Seems this is an important feature to support.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [FHIR build for DSTU2](http://hl7.org/fhir/2015May), I would say this feedback has been addressed.  The doseQuantity element has been replaced by a dose[x] element which can be either a range or a quantity:  http://hl7.org/fhir/2015May/medicationprescription-definitions.html#MedicationPrescription.dosageInstruction.dose_x_